# HTML5 Audio not Playing Valid Source

Tags: javascript, html, audio, html5-audio

I have a lot of `audio` tags that I'm loading onto a page (potentially hundreds) and some of them are correctly loading their `src` media, but others do not. The source media is completely valid and the elements that load and don't load are inconsistent. That is, some elements will load properly one time, but upon refresh they fail. I'm testing on Chrome.

Here's an example of one of the tags:

```
<li>
<h3>Episode 21: Daylight Saving</h3>
<audio src="http://traffic.libsyn.com/pragmatic/Pragmatic-E021.mp3" controls=""></audio>
</li>
```

Comment: Can you add a link to a page of what you're trying to do?

Comment: No, I'm developing locally. I added a full example of one of the list items, but there's really not any more complexity than this.

Comment: Are you opening files from `file://` URLs - sometimes this affects the behavior.

Comment: I'm not but that's a great point. I've had that cause issues before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an odd memory issue. Setting `preload = "none"` on all of the audio elements seems to have fixed it. If you have fewer elements than I, you may be able to get away with `preload = "metadata"`.

Comment: Always mention the web browser you are using, because it is the most relevant for this kind of question and behavior like this varies from browser to browser.

Comment: Excellent recommendation. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a memory problem or browser implementation problem. There is no easy diagnostic with the info provided. Try to use the  "onError" attribute to log a detailed error into the (onError) callback.
Try also to launch your browser from the console to see STDOUT/STDERR errors.